# How to read the data-product_id from the following code

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a script that in woocommerce catches me an event of adding a product to my cart.

```
    <script>
        (function($){
           $('body').on( 'added_to_cart', function(e, fragments, cart_hash, this_button){
              console.log('this_button:',this_button);
           });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

After pressing the ADD_TO_CART button in the

```
console.log(this_button);
```

I get this answer and in it I see my desired product_id

```
this_button: 
{…}
​
0: <a class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart added" href="/Blog/produkt/klawwa/?add-to-cart=14" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="14" data-product_sku="" aria-label="Dodaj “Fajna flaszka” do koszyka" rel="nofollow">
​
context: <a class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart added" href="/Blog/produkt/klawwa/?add-to-cart=14" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="14" data-product_sku="" aria-label="Dodaj “Fajna flaszka” do koszyka" rel="nofollow">
​
length: 1
​
selector: ""
​
__proto__: Object { jquery: "1.12.4", constructor: n(), length: 0, … }
```

And now the question how to find the value of data-product_id from this sequence.
The question is not actually related to woocomerce but to JS itself.
Thank you in advance for all your help.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've already completed it,

Comment: If you found the solution, please post an answer so we all can learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the value by adding this to your `.click()` function.

```
$(this).data('product_id');
```

TRY:

```
 <script>
        (function($){
           $('body').on( 'added_to_cart', function(e, fragments, cart_hash, this_button){
              console.log($(this_button).data('product_id'));
           });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but my knowledge of JS is really minimal and I don't know what to do about it.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can suggest you is to try call:

```
console.log(this_button.context['data-product_id'])
//returns undefined
```

or

```
console.log(this_button[0]['data-product_id'])
```

And remember to drink this flaszka responsibly. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, he's returning: undefined

`<script>
            (function($){
               $('body').on( 'added_to_cart', function(e, fragments, cart_hash, this_button){

          console.log(this_button.context['data-product_id'])
               });
            })(jQuery);
        </script>`