# Woocommerce trigger added_to_cart and get product ID

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

On Woocommerce, with jQuery, there is a way to retriev product id added to cart with ajax when trigger 'added_to_cart'?

e.g

```
$( document.body ).on( 'added_to_cart', function() { 
    // print the product id added on console
});
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the question ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read the data-product\_id from the following code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55922697/how-to-read-the-data-product-id-from-the-following-code)

Comment: @anjanesh It seems like the OP is trying to get the product id in the context of the `added_to_cart` event

Answer (score 1):

*This is just a hack*

I was unable to get it either but I figured you can catch that event alongside with some parameters `(event, fragments, cart_hash, $button)`. The fourth is quite interesting as it returns you the DOMElement of the button you just pressed.

In your theme, I suggest you to add an attribute to your ADD_TO_CART button
eg: `<button data-product_id="1234"> ... </button>`

Then your .js file would finally look something like:

```js
$(document.body).on("added_to_cart", function (event, fragments, cart_hash, $button) {
    console.log($($button[0]).data('product_id'));
});
```